# How to leave a war in which you are not the main attacker/defender?

Tags: stellaris

I was invited into a war via a defensive pact and we're losing terribly. The problem is, even if the warscore is below -50%, the main defender has not yet sent their peace terms and I'm stuck fighting the enemy myself. Is there a way to stop my involvement abruptly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

You can minimise losses by keeping your fleet out of the way, but there's not much you can do if the enemy decides to attack your territory or, worse, cede your planets.

In future, you can avoid this by not making defensive pacts that you don't want to have to honour.

Comment: A lesson I also had to learn the hard way.  Defensive pacts seem like a great idea until you loose systems in someone else's war.  Choose your allies carefully!

Comment: Reminds me of that one time where I had an early game defensive pact with an AI who considered it a good idea to build a frontier outpost next to a Militant Isolationist fallen empire.